# can I use React Native Paper for the normal reactjs web application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

can I use `React Native Paper` package for the normal `reactjs` `web` application?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I misread the question. I don't know actually if you can use it for reactjs without react-native.

You might want to look at https://tamagui.dev/ though, which promises to work fine on both web (with just ReactJS) and native (with React Native).

My original answer below is for those who wants to use it for web with React Native for Web:

---

On their website they write that you can: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/react-native-web/

Personally I didn't try it myself, but I tried to play with their examples, which you also can try on web: https://snack.expo.dev/@react-native-paper/react-native-paper-example_v5 (you have to wait for about 10 seconds after loading - until you have it running on the right side).

So honestly I didn't like too much what I saw. Selecting first item ("Animated Floating Action Button") and we see that button is not visible - until you scroll down whole list of all items (while it should be always-on-top, so we immediately see the bug), and also layout for button is bad - text overflows incorrectly:

[image: bad layout of React Native Paper example on web]

Then I downloaded iOS version - it looks much better there. Still not perfect (for example, when I start typing on textfield that is closer to bottom of my screen, then virtual keyboard pops up completely covering the textbox, so I don't see what I'm typing, while other UI libraries normally scroll my screen up when keyboard pops up and then returns back when keyboard disappears).

Answer (score -1):

They have some information about it in their docs?
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/using-on-the-web.html.

Comment: please add one positive point to my question

Comment: I had this question and this answer doesn't help because the link is dead.

Comment: Updated link: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/react-native-web/